# Missing artifact when trying to add spring-data

Tags: spring, maven, spring-data

I am trying to add the spring data dependency to my Spring boot starter project but I am getting the error: `Missing artifact org.springframework.data:spring-data-jdbc-ext:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE`

Here is my pom.xml file. What am I missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc-ext</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.test.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: If you browse to [those coordinates](http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jdbc-core/1.0.0.RELEASE/) you can see there is indeed no jar there.  It doesn't show up on any other maven searches either.  Maybe try `spring-data-jdbc-core` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason the documentation on the [Spring Data JDBC Extensions](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jdbc-ext/) website is wrong (or the distribution is wrong!).

According to that page you, indeed, need to include the dependency you mention.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc-ext</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

However if you take a look in [the spring repository](http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jdbc-ext/1.0.0.RELEASE/) for that artifact it contains a zip file with the release instead of a jar or pom file.

The spring-data-jdbc-ext project consists of 2 artifacts, which both are available. Change your dependency to the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-oracle</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't need the specific Oracle extensions than you could leave that one out.

A small note there is a 1.1.0.M1 version also (a milestone/pre-release versio) which works with a newer version of Spring Data. You might want to try that instead of the 1.0.0.RELEASE version which was build against an older version of Spring Data.

Comment: Marten's suggestion is correct. There is a bug in the spring.io website and we will correct that. In the meantime use the dependencies suggested here.